# Boo, garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection, boo

does Boo have a garbage collector?
what type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, as provided by the CLR.
2. Depends on the implementation of the runtime.

   - For Microsoft .NET, it is using a 3 Generational GC, see [*.NET Development (General) Technical Articles: Garbage Collector Basics and Performance Hints*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx).
   - For Mono, [it is using the Boehm conservative GC](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Garbage_Collection), but is migrating to a new Generational, Precise GC.

Comment: Actually, the boehm gc already uses a generational algorithm, see [here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/#details) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector#Method_of_Operation).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a .NET/CLR language, it relies on the garbage collector provided by that infrastructure. Although the garbage collector is an implementation detail to the infrastructure.

The two main CLR implementations are the Microsoft .NET Framework and the mono project.
If you're interested, you can read about the implementation of the [MS.NET GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) or the [Mono GC](http://www.mono-project.com/Compacting_GC).